# Passenger does not start Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, passenger

I am not sure if this is the correct part of the log

```
[ 2013-06-27 08:00:08.2593 16832/7fcf8d7a4740 agents/HelperAgent/Main.cpp:555 ]: PassengerHelperAgent online, listening at unix:/tmp/passenger.1.0.7663/generation-0/request
[Thu Jun 27 08:00:08 2013] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) Phusion_Passenger/4.0.5 configured -- resuming normal operations
[ 2013-06-27 08:00:08.2793 16829/7fc55d714740 agents/Watchdog/Main.cpp:564 ]: All Phusion Passenger agents started!
[ 2013-06-27 08:00:08.2794 16837/7fbb5e4c7740 agents/LoggingAgent/Main.cpp:271 ]: PassengerLoggingAgent online, listening at unix:/tmp/passenger.1.0.7663/generation-0/logging
[ 2013-06-27 08:00:14.7386 16832/7fcf8d6ee700 Pool2/Spawner.h:739 ]: [App 16906 stdout] 
[ 2013-06-27 08:01:44.5986 16832/7fcf8d6ee700 Pool2/Implementation.cpp:774 ]: Could not spawn process for group /home/ubuntu/my_app/current#default: An error occurred while starting up the preloader: it did not write a startup response in time.
     in 'void Passenger::ApplicationPool2::SmartSpawner::throwPreloaderSpawnException(const string&, Passenger::SpawnException::ErrorKind, Passenger::ApplicationPool2::Spawner::BackgroundIOCapturerPtr&, const DebugDirPtr&)' (SmartSpawner.h:150)
     in 'std::string Passenger::ApplicationPool2::SmartSpawner::negotiatePreloaderStartup(Passenger::ApplicationPool2::SmartSpawner::StartupDetails&)' (SmartSpawner.h:558)
     in 'void Passenger::ApplicationPool2::SmartSpawner::startPreloader()' (SmartSpawner.h:206)
     in 'virtual Passenger::ApplicationPool2::ProcessPtr Passenger::ApplicationPool2::SmartSpawner::spawn(const Passenger::ApplicationPool2::Options&)' (SmartSpawner.h:744)
     in 'void Passenger::ApplicationPool2::Group::spawnThreadRealMain(const SpawnerPtr&, const Passenger::ApplicationPool2::Options&, unsigned int)' (Implementation.cpp:707)
```

I read redirecting STDOUT could cause the problem, I searched STDOUT in all my config directory, but I am not using it.

In apache config file I have:

```
LoadModule passenger_module /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p429/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-4.0.5/libout/apache2/mod_passenger.so
PassengerRoot /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p429/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-4.0.5
PassengerDefaultRuby /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p429/bin/ruby

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName ip_with_numbers
  # !!! Be sure to point DocumentRoot to 'public'!
  DocumentRoot /home/ubuntu/my_app/current/public
  <Directory /home/ubuntu/my_app/current/public>
    # This relaxes Apache security settings.
    AllowOverride all
    # MultiViews must be turned off.
    Options -MultiViews
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

And I have also these outputs:

With `sudo`:

```
sudo passenger-memory-stats
command not found
```

W/o `sudo`:

```
passenger-memory-stats
...
17671  216.1 MB  ?        PassengerWatchdog
17674  562.6 MB  ?        PassengerHelperAgent
17679  165.7 MB  ?        PassengerLoggingAgent
```

And here is an image of page I am getting:

[image: the page I am getting]

What am I missing?

Comment: did you find a way to fix this issue?

Comment: hmm, no. I reinstalled in an Ubuntu AMI which has nothing of the stack installed.

Comment: the sudo error is probably normal if you are running RVM
it might be nothing, but you could try to do a bundle update and service apache2 restart afterwards. I had the exact same problem once and this solved it.

Comment: also, I've seen that you're running on AWS. if this is a micro instance, sometimes it takes quite a long time to boot a rails app.